# SQL every month basis report.

Tags: sql

I have a 2 year data in SQL and i want to create or write query will be pull out data monthly basis. How do i write query which will give me every month data in one shot.

Jan  Feb Mar Apil ....etc

Comment: what have you tried?  can you post some sample data and your expected results?

Comment: In general, you select some aggregate function (sum,count, etc) and group by month. Different RDMS have different datetime functions that return date part (month in your case). Then you use `PIVOT` if your server supports it, or write an analogue with `MAX(CASE WHEN month_field=01 THEN value_field END) AS Jan,...`. Without any details from you I cannot give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT myField1,myField2,...MONTH(myDateField) as monthDate,YEAR(myDateField) as yearDate 
FROM myTableName ORDER BY yearDate,monthDate
```

Comment: group by required each field of select statement in you group by list